# Clone React JSX Element with nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, clone, next.js

I faced with some problem. I have heavy JSX Element with multipe states. In another part of app I need to pass this Element to Modal window with keeping all states. What is the best solution for solving this problem? Of course I can make Parent with all states and pass it to Child. But maybe it's possible to freeze all states and pass JSX Element as independent component?

Structure will look like:

```
ParentElement
|_
   AnotherElement
|_
   SomeHeavyElement
```

ParentElement:

```
const ParentElement= () => {
       return (
              <React.Fragment>
                  <AnotherElement />
                  <SomeHeavyElement />
              </React.Fragment>
       );
};
export default ParentElement;
```

AnotherElement:

```
const AnotherElement= () => {
       return (
              <React.Fragment>
                  <dialog>
                      <SomeHeavyElement/>
                  </dialog>
              </React.Fragment>
       );
};
export default AnotherElement;
```

SomeHeavyElement

```
const SomeHeavyElement= () => {
       const [state1, setState1] = useState(true);
       ...
       const [state99, setState99] = useState(false);

       return (
              <React.Fragment>
                 {/*some logic*/}
              </React.Fragment>
       );
};
export default SomeHeavyElement;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), meaning you should define your state on top of both component (in `<ParentElement>`). You can't really freeze your component internal state.

Here is a minimal example:

```js
const ParentElement= () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(true); 
  // ...
  const [state99, setState99] = useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AnotherElement state={{state1, state99}} />
      <SomeHeavyElement state={{state1, state99}} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ParentElement;
```

```js
const SomeHeavyElement= ({state}) => {  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/*some logic*/}
    </React.Fragment> 
  );
};
export default SomeHeavyElement;
```

```js
const AnotherElement= ({state}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <dialog>
        <SomeHeavyElement state={state} />
      </dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AnotherElement;
```

Also, when you have a lot of `useState` defined, you could `useReducer` to centralize your component state. Also, if you want to avoid props drilling, you could define handle your state using React API context.